# Exporting to mov file for transparency turn the smoke of a fire pixelated, how to avoid it?

Tags: rendering, file-format

I'm using Blender 2.93.4. I created a fire with a smoke using this tutorial,

[Blender Tutorial - Low Poly Fire Animation (2.91)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzf2sYhbm1Y)

Then, I exported a file to mov extension for having a transparent background using this tutorial,

[Export Video with Transparent Background in Blender 2.9/2.8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4emIy6vevcI)

using the options File Format FFmpeg video, container Quicktime, videocodec QT rle/QT animation.

I'm having the problem that exporting it like this turn the smoke of the fire to be pixelated. I thought that may be some of the options below the codec are the problem, but I dont know how to set them if that's the case.

How do I do to avoid the smoke of my fire to be pixelated when I export to mov format for having a transparent background?

Answer (score 0):

First things first: Bad tutorial!
Why, you ask? because that dude directly exported as video. That is a Nono, my guy.
What you want to do first is: Export your animation as individual frames.
Why, you ask?
Because you can render as png with transparency in high quality. If your render crashes you still have the progress you have made with the finished images, so no need to start over, just start where Blender left off.
Then you can use this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bgab9VC_laQ

To get the image sequence into a video within Blender and try to use AVI instead of Quicktime, as that also supports transparency.
OR:
Go ahead and download davinci resolve. It is free and you will definitely be able to export high quality video out of it with transparency.

Hope this helps!